# Convert af::array to af_array and back

Tags: c#, c++, arrayfire

I would like to use the [ArrayFire](https://github.com/arrayfire) library to run multiple artificial neural networks on the GPU in parallel.

Since I am mainly a C# developer I tried to realize it via [SiaNet](https://github.com/SciSharp/SiaNet). But I encountered the problem that SiaNet can only run one neural network at a time.

This is because SiaNet and the [C# API of ArrayFire](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire-dotnet) do not implement the [`batchFunc`](http://arrayfire.org/docs/namespaceaf.htm#aa0eb9e160f5be4b95234543e5c47934b) function.

I wanted to make up for this and built my own little library.
There I call the `batchFunc` function and want to build an API which can be called from C# with PInvokes.

The problem is that I can only use `af_array` from C#, but the `batchFunc` function can only process `af::array`. Therefore I need to convert one into the other.

My `MatrixMultiply` function, to have a function that I can pass `batchFunc`:

```
af::array MatrixMultiply(const af::array &lhs, const af::array &rhs) {
    return matmul(lhs, rhs);
}
```

My PInvoke friendly function:

```
af_err BatchMatmul(af_array *out, const af::array lhs, const af::array rhs) {
    try
    {
    *out = &(af::batchFunc(lhs, rhs, MatrixMultiply));

    return AF_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (af::exception& e) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
    return AF_ERR_BATCH;
    }
}
```

As I call it on C# side:

```
[DllImport("BatchOpsWrapperLib.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern af_err BatchMatmul(out IntPtr array_out, IntPtr array_lhs, IntPtr array_rhs);
```

I have hardly or not at all worked with C/C++ so far and would like to ask you for help here.

**Edit:**
This is my reworked new function:

```
af_err BatchMatmul(af_array *out, const af_array lhs, const af_array rhs)
{
    try
    {
        af_array retainedLhs = 0;
        af_array retainedRhs = 0;

        af_retain_array(&retainedLhs, lhs);
        af_retain_array(&retainedRhs, rhs);

        af_array resultHandle = 0;

        af_retain_array(&resultHandle, af::batchFunc(af::array(retainedLhs),
                                                     af::array(retainedRhs),
                                                     MatrixMultiply).get());

        *out = resultHandle;

        return AF_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (af::exception& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        return AF_ERR_BATCH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `af::array` instance has a method `.get()`, from which you can retrieve an `af_array` instance.

```
af::array some_array = ...;
af_array c_array = some_array.get();
```

You can also construct an `af::array` from an `af_array` using `af::array(some_af_array)`.

```
af::array another_array = af::array(c_array);`
```

Comment: The following should be added.

The conversion via the constructor only works if you use [`af_retain_array`](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__method__mat.htm#ga7ed45b3f881c0f6c80c5cf2af886dbab).

Otherwise you get a `NullPointerException`.